# Full width image with 960px container

Tags: html, css, containers

I have a full width image and caption which sits within a section, like so:

```
<section id="featured">
    <img src="images/featured.jpg" alt="My Image">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="caption">
            <h1>Here's a title</h1>
            <p>With a caption</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#featured {
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 24px;
    left: 0;
}
```

The container sits below the image with zero height. This ensures the caption stays in line with the rest of the body content. It also works well with the media queries as you reduce the viewport width.

My question: Is there anything wrong with the container having a height of zero? Could this prevent the caption from showing on certain devices? It works perfectly in IE7+ and the iPad2.

I've seen examples where the developer hasn't used a container, but absolute positioning purely on the caption. This means you have to set several breakpoints, which I'd prefer to avoid.

You can see a working version here: http://bit.ly/1txE7Zi

Comment: The only problem would be if you wanted to put something below the caption and it was too long so it came out of the banner - if you're not going to or the caption will always stay within the banner then it doesn't matter

Comment: Ah just looked at your site and it is unlikely that the caption would come out of the banner.  One question though - why not just make `featured` relative and position `caption` to the bottom of that?  Would mean you didn't actually need the container div

Comment: Hey @Pete. Thanks for your feedback :) I'd like the caption to be inline with the body content. It's been easier to create a container for responsive. It means the caption will stay put as you reduce the viewport width.

Comment: ah yes, again I didn't look at the code properly. Just seen the container is 960 and featured is 100%.  D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

According to the W3, absolutely positioned items will shrink to fit their contents. You can also set the `top` and `bottom` properties, or `height` property to give the container a height.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Specifying_dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem at all. It only has a height of 0px because its children are positioned absolutely. You shouldn't have any issues with it displaying incorrectly on devices.